# IntelliJ throws "init terminating in do_boot", but same erl command works in Windows command line

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang

Setup: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2, Erlang 25.0

I am trying to run the Erlang code available at https://erlangbyexample.org/send-receive. I am able to run in werl and Windows command line. But I am getting the error "init terminating in do_boot" when I run in IntelliJ.

I checked a similar issue reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091487/init-terminating-in-do-boot-is-thrown-when-executing-erlang-script) , wherein the solution was to convert list input to integer/s. However, my Erlang code does not expect any input, it just expects the function name.

Please provide a pointer to resolve the issue.

```
"C:\Program Files\Erlang OTP\bin\erl.exe" -pa F:/1TB/P/workspace-IntelliJ-Erlang1/out/production/workspace-IntelliJ-Erlang1 -pa F:/1TB/P/workspace-IntelliJ-Erlang1 -eval send_recv:run(). -s init stop -noshell
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{send_recv,run,[],[]},{erl_eval,do_apply,7,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,744}]},{init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1234}]},{init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1220}]},{init,do_boot,3,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,910}]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ({undef,[{send_recv,run,[],[]},{erl_eval,do_apply,7,[{_},{_}]},{init,start_it,1,[{_},{_}]},{init,start_em,1,[{_},{_}]},{init,do_boot,3,[{_},{_}]}]})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

[image: IntelliJ Run Configuration]

[image: Windows Command Line]

[image: werl shell]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I configured RunConfiguration to BUILD before RUNNING ("Before launch" section). As result, RunConfiguration was creating an empty folder "../out/production/workspace-IntelliJ-Erlang1" without .beam files, if the folder does not exist. It would delete any existing .beam files if the folder exists. Hence, the RUN was failing eventually.

As a workaround, I removed the BUILD before RUNNING option from RunConfiguration. And, I manually built using BuildProject before RunConfiguration.

TODO: I will check why was not RunConfiguration able to generate the .beam file.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is a file called `send_recv.beam` in either of the directories specified as code path in the `-pa` arguments.  (The `undef` error means that it can't find the function `send_recv:run/0`, more often than not because it can't find the compiled module.)

My guess is that this file is actually in the directory where you ran Erlang from the command prompt, but IntelliJ runs Erlang using another working directory. The current working directory is part of the code path by default, which would be why this works from the command prompt but not within IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks @legoscia. You are right. send_recv.beam is not present in the directory specified by the -pa argument. I need to debug further why is the .beam file not generated.